# I want the number of unique values in each of the columns in a matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I want  the number of unique values in each of the columns in a matrix. Let's say I have the following matrix:

```
 id  val 
1000 32 
1001 27 
1003 27 
1007 27
1109 32
1234 11
2345 11
4567 10
5000 9
```

then it should return

```
id               val    freq
1000, 1109       32     2
1001, 1003, 1007 27     3   
1234, 2345       11     2
4567             10     1
5000              9     1
```

I am using the following codes:

```
mat %>% group_by(id, val) %>% mutate(count = n())
```

and

```
mat %>% group_by(id, val) %>% tally()
```

Any suggestions

Comment: probaly yes... but please provide some better (relevant) sample data to experiment on. use `dput` to crete a reproducible example.

Comment: I see `uktus15_diary_wide` is used to create `Activities`, but what *is* it?

Comment: Please include the output of either `dput(Activities)` or `dput(uktus15_diary_wide)` in your question. Otherwise it's not reproducible, and your chances of getting help are much lower that way.